# iOS Swift 4: UIView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, isuserinteractionenabled

I have a `UIImageView` with a tap gesture recognizer as a subview of a `UIScrollView`.

A.) If the `UIImageView` `isUserInteractionEnabled=false` the scroll view works fine (pinch zoom, scroll) but doesn't recognize the tap gesture on the image.

B.) If `isUserInteractionEnabled=true` I cannot start pinch zoom or scroll from the image but the tap gesture works.

How can I manage it to work (keep scrolling and zooming but recognize tap on content)?

Comment: add the tap gesture to scrollview, if possible

Comment: can it help 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer?changes=_7

Comment: The scrollview contains a map as an imageView and I have to tap markers on it. So I think the scrollView tap gesture won't help me out.

Comment: try to implement [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer?changes=_7) in gesture delegate

Answer (score 1):

Because UIScrollView has gestures within for handling scroll, pinch, it means when your UIImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true, the UIImageView' tap gesture take those touches and do not forward it to UISCrollView.

Here is the solution by implementing a UIGesture's delegate method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures

Comment: There's no gesture recognizer on the UIimageView (the map) but I cannot set isUserInteractionEnabled=false because it has subviews (also UIImageViews but smaller 'the markers') which has recognizers. The problem is with the map (parent UIImageView) which hasn't got any recognizers.

Comment: Don't worry, just implement method shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer, don't forget to set your marker'gesture delegate, every gesture in your view controller will work simultaneously.